# MySql Python Adapter Installation Problem on Windows 7 Machine

Tags: python, mysql, windows-7

C:\Users\Me>easy_install  MySQL-python

Searching for MySQL-python

Reading [http://pypi.python.org/simple/MySQL-python/

Reading [http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/

Reading [http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python

Best match: MySQL-python 1.2.3

Downloading [http://download.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/mysql-python/MySQL-pytho
n-1.2.3.tar.gz

Processing MySQL-python-1.2.3.tar.gz

Running MySQL-python-1.2.3\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\Me\appdata
\local\temp\easy_install-ag_30a\MySQL-python-1.2.3\egg-dist-tmp-mbyihd

**error: The system cannot find the file specified**

**Why is it looking there?** (c:\users\Me\appdata
\local\temp\easy_install-ag_30a\MySQL-python-1.2.3\egg-dist-tmp-mbyihd)

**Note**: I added '[' before all http tags because new users can't place more than two links.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the binaries from here, http://www.codegood.com/archives/129, which will bypass easy_install all together. Plus, stop using easy_install, use pip, it's much better.

Comment: @Milli No problem man, I had the same problem when I was working with SQL, but caps isn't necessary man. Everyone knows good programmers give themselves a second ctrl key :P